# Dynamically sort files into different folders based on file extension as they are created

Tags: windows-10, batch, file-extension, folder-redirection

I'm working with an apparel CAD system (Lectra Modaris) that automatically generates 3 files when I save.  There is an .MDL file, an .HTML file and and .XCH file.

I want the HTML files to automatically save in a different folder from the MDL files (I don't care what happens to the XCH files because I don't use them).

I've spoken with the CAD system vendor and they say they can't help with this, but I'm wondering if there is anything I can do from Windows to make this happen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this.

You can use a lot of different scripting languages that run natively on Windows. .bat Batch, .vbs Visual Basic, .ps1 PowerShell, and .js JavaScript.

The automation aspect of your particular problem set has different approaches as well.

1. You could write the script so that it waits for changes from your app.
2. You could schedule the script to run in Windows Task Scheduler every 15 minutes; or whatever interval you want.

The Windows code you can use is really simple, portable to all versions of Windows for PCs, and anyone could use it. This is what I will provide below; it will be in the Batch .bat scripting language. Since I dont know your level of experience I will assume you have never worked with .bat scripts.

The 2 commands you need to know about are cd and copy.exe.
The Windows Scripting skills required are few in number as well.
1.  A .bat or .cmd file is a Windows Batch or Command script.
    - When you create a .bat file its a set of instruction to the computer. If 
      you write the string "Hello World" in a .bat file nothing would happen but 
      if you put echo "Hello World" the "program" would display the string hello 
      world.
2.  So much can go wrong.
    - Even though this (Scripting "Programming") all sounds simple there are so 
      many ways for things to go wrong and cause real-world problems, in your 
     case maybe deleting your employers' files. I'll put some comments in the 
     script below thatll describe just 1 example of how things could go wrong.

```
REM 2.1 Lines of text where beginning of the line has the word REM are 
    ways to put comments in a script. The echo command is the 3rd command 
    but isnt necessary.

REM This next line of code is required for decent display.
@Echo Off

REM 1. Syntax for the cd (Acronym for Change Directory) command is:
REM    CD "SomeFolders full directory path"
REM                  OR
REM    CD "SomeFolder inside the current folders path"
REM                  OR
REM    CD
REM    Using the command cd without anything after it will show your 
       current directory (Your current location)

REM 2. Syntax for the copy command is:
REM    Copy SourceFolder DestinationFolder
REM                  Or
REM    Copy SourceFoldersWildCards DestinationFolder

REM 1.  Change directory to where your files are.
REM You will have to change "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files" to the location 
    of your files. I just used this as an example.

REM 2.2 DoubleQuotes are excellent practice b/c all commands don't know how to deal with it when they are not present.
CD "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files"

REM Now that you are in another folder you can use relative references.
REM 2. Do some file copying.
REM This is a purposefully incorrect line of code to show what can go wrong.
Copy *.MDL C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files\The MDL Files
REM Copy doesnt know what to do because there are no DoubleQuotes. 
Thankfully it doesnt do any copying and instead gives you an error message.

Copy *.MDL "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files\The MDL Files"
Copy *.HTML "My Work Files\The HTML Files"
Del *.XCH
REM Copied any file with the .MDL file extension
REM - into a folder named "The MDL Files"
REM - using absolute references.
REM Copied *.HTML files to a folder named "The HTML Files"
REM - using relative references.
REM Deleted .xch files using relative references.
REM 3.0 Del was undiscussed and makes 4 commands, 3 of which are necessary.
```

Below is a version of the script with no comments.

```
@Echo Off
CD "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files"
Copy *.MDL  "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files\The MDL Files"
Copy *.HTML "My Work Files\The HTML Files"
Del  *.XCH
```

Improved version. The IF Statement.

```
@Echo Off
CD "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files"
IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="C:\Users\Liz E\My-Work-Files" GOTO :EOF
Copy *.MDL  "C:\Users\Liz E\My-Work-Files\The-MDL-Files"
Copy *.HTML "C:\Users\Liz E\My-Work-Files\The-HTML-Files"
Del  C:\Users\Liz E\My-Work-Files\*.XCH"
```

Improved version with automation.

```
@Echo Off
REM Set/configure the work folder in C:\My-Work-Files
REM Helps if ur work files are approaching length limit for windows files.
REM Note though you may have to deal with the folders permissions if you
REM put it outside your userprofile. This applies if your concerned about
REM someone else deleting your files or something.
REM Set/configure the work folder in C:\Users\Liz E\My-Work-Files
REM The 2nd line of code "overwrites/takes precedence" over the first one.
Set "MyWorkFiles="%SystemDrive%\My-Work-Files"
Set "MyWorkFiles="%UserProfile%\My-Work-Files"
Set "MDLFilesDest=UserProfile%\My-Work-Files\The-MDL-Files"
REM Set "HTMLFilesDest=UserProfile%\My-Work-Files\The-HTML-Files"

CD "%MyWorkFiles%"
REM If CurrentDirectory isnt right return/dont do anymore of the script.
IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="%MyWorkFiles%" (
    Echo Oops. I must have moved, renamed, or deleted the folder.
    Echo Returning from the script.
    Pause
    GOTO :EOF
)

:Begin
Copy "%MyWorkFiles%\*.MDL"  "%MDLFilesDest%"                             2>Nul
Copy "%MyWorkFiles%\*.HTML" "%UserProfile%\My Work Files\The-HTML-Files" 2>Nul
Del  "%UserProfile%\My Work Files\*.XCH"                                 2>Nul

REM TheAutomationLine. Wait/"pause" for 60 seconds.
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60 >Nul

REM Go the the label/section of the script marked as :Begin
REM Effectively this script will run forever; until you close it.
REM You can minimize it and it will work in the "background"
GOTO :Begin
```

The above script[s] can do no wrong as there are no syntax bugs/errors in em.
Yes the third one introduced the forth command in, "IF". The last script has yet some more "new" commands.

All of these are present in the last script.

1. One way to improve it would be to not have spaces in the filenames.
2. Another way is to use "C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files*.html" instead of just *.html but both are correct and will work perfectly.
3. Another way is to add some code safety/code checks such as checking to see/verifying the current directory and returning/exiting the script if (for some almost impossible reason) the cd command didnt work.

This line of code in script 3. IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="C:\Users\Liz E\My Work Files" GOTO:EOF

4. Using the built-in Batch scripting variables SystemDrive/UserProfile, others.

However, between it sitting on a webpage and you copying/pasting it into NotePad or the text editor of your choice believe it or not something could go wrong.

The resulting problem would be the same as in the example I provided in the 1st/heavily commented script above. The double quotes syntax error which would result in your script doing nothing. Who knows tho could do something else on some other windows edition.

The problem is that the text being copied is in a different encoding and when pasted is that encoding. The encoding results in charachters that .bat scripts doesnt understand.

So most of the above non-commented code will be the same; roughly 90%. What will be different is the double quotes. They will be in that different encoding. You can select the quote charachter and use Find/Replace in NotePad to replace what looks like a perfectly good double quote charachter (although you can notice it looks like an italicized one) with one you manually type into the "Replace With" dialog in NotePad.

See the linked article at the bottom of this posting if this sounds difficult or you want to download some cool applications to deal with this encoding problem.

Copy/Pasting Problem Solved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/how-to-copy-and-paste-code-without-rich-text-formatting